# How to convert a href and img to php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code

```
echo "<img src='" . $image[0] . "'>";
```

And this

```
<a href="/images/preview-kv/1.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="images/preview-kv/1.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

I need to convert this to php with dynamic image... pls

Comment: Answer is already give from your side. Please write down the same syntax as your write down for img tag.

Answer (score 0):

`$image` is an array.

Assume `$image = array("/images/preview-kv/image1.png","/images/preview-kv/image2.png");`

```
    foreach($image as $image_path)
    {
      ?>
      <!--$image_value is dynamically changed-->        
      <a href="<?php echo $image_path; ?>"   data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="<?php echo $image_path; ?>" alt=""></a>
     <?php
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these. I have taken Your `path` and `src` in `variable` as example

```
$path = "/images/preview-kv/1.jpg";
$src = "images/preview-kv/1.jpg";
 echo '<a href="'.$path.'" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="'.$src.'" alt=""></a>';
```

or

```
 <a href="<?php echo $path ?>" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="<?php echo $src ?>" alt=""></a>
```